# Using Tweepy to Obtain Most Recent Tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I was using Tweepy and wanted to get the link of the most recent tweet from a user. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
ckey = '-----------------------------------'
csecret = '-------------------------------------------------'
atoken = '---------------------'
asecret = '-------------------'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = api.home_timeline()
tweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'realDonaldTrump', count = 100, 
include_rts = True)[0]
link = api.get_oembed(https://twitter.com/{}/status/{}.format(tweet.user.screen_n‌ame, tweet.id)).url
print(tweet.text)
```

Here is the traceback I get:

```
link = api.get_oembed(https://twitter.com/{}/status/{}.format(tweet.user.screen_n‌​ame, tweet.id)).url
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know I have a syntax issue, but I also think there is an overarching problem with the line itself, whether it's with my parentheses or with my commands. I know my OAuth is working because when I take out that line, I get something for print(text.tweet). Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You need to put quotes around the URL like so: `link = api.get_oembed("https://twitter.com/{}/status/{}".format(tweet.user.screen_n‌ame, tweet.id)).url`

Comment: @kstullich I did it and got a new traceback. "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier" on the comma between screen_name and tweet.id. I also removed the tweet.user because I was getting an error there, and I presume there will be one on the tweet.id))

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere? Do you see how PyCharm is showing that error on the right ([code screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/qVznb))? Just re-write those 2 variables and that should fix it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!